# View Both Assembly and C code

Tags: gdb

Do we have a way to view assembly and c code both using gdb.

disassemble function_name shows only assembly, I was trying to find a way to easliy map c code to assembly.
Thanks

Answer (score 66, accepted):

You can run gdb in *Text User Interface* (TUI) mode:

```
gdb -tui <your-binary>
(gdb) b main
(gdb) r
(gdb) layout split
```

The `layout split` command divides the window into two parts - one of them displaying the source code, the other one the corresponding assembly.
A few others tricks:

- *set disassembly-flavor intel* - if your prefer intel notation
- *set print asm-demangle* - demangles C++ names in assembly view
- *ni* - next instruction
- *si* - step instruction

If you do not want to use the TUI mode (e.g. your terminal does not like it), you can always do:

```
x /12i $pc
```

which means *print 12 instructions from current program counter address* - this also works with the tricks above (demangling, stepping instructions, etc.).

The "x /12i $pc" trick works in both gdb and cgdb, whereas "layout split" only works in gdb.

Enjoy :)

Comment: Is there any way to also get rid of top split window? It's unncessary and takes space.

Comment: @BabkenVardanyan Try `layout next`. If it does not give you the desired layout try this command a few more times. This command keeps switching between layouts so you can keep the one you want.

Comment: Any way to also see the register as in `layout regs`?

Answer (score 44):

Try `disassemble /m`.

Refer to http://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Machine-Code.html#Machine-Code

The format is similar to that of `objdump -S`, and intermixes source with disassembly. Sample output excerpt:

```
10      int i = 0;
=> 0x0000000000400536 <+9>: movl   $0x0,-0x14(%rbp)

11      while (1) {
12          i++;
   0x000000000040053d <+16>:    addl   $0x1,-0x14(%rbp)
```

Comment: I didn't want the other solutions because I don't want to restart gdb and get it set up the same way again and the .o file's references to relocated sections make it hard to understand.  So I thought this was just the ticket.  Imagine my horror, then, when I eventually realized that disassemble/m silently omits some instructions, like after the first, three byte instruction:

`   0x000000000442f038 <+24>: mov    %rsi,%rbx
   0x000000000442f043 <+35>: sub    $0x38,%rsp`

That's `GNU gdb (GDB) 7.4.1-debian`.

Comment: The gdb docs discourage `/m` and suggest `/s` instead: "The /m option is deprecated as its output is not useful when there is either inlined code or re-ordered code. The /s option is the preferred choice. Here is an example for AMD x86-64 showing the difference between /m output and /s output. This example has one inline function defined in a header file, and the code is compiled with ‘-O2’ optimization. Note how the /m output is missing the disassembly of several instructions that are present in the /s output."  -- https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Machine-Code.html

Answer (score 9):

For your purpose, try

```
objdump -S <your_object_file>
```

from man objdump:

```
-S
--source
 Display source code intermixed with disassembly, if possible.
 Implies -d.
```

Answer (score 2):

The fastest way to obtain this is to press the key combination `ctrl-x 2` after launching `gdb`.

This will give you immediately a split window with source code and assembly in Text User Interface Mode (described in accepted answer).

Just another tooltip: keyboard arrows in this mode are used for navigate up and down through the source code, to use them to access commands history you can use `ctrl-x o` that will refocus on gdb shell window.