# Map disassembly .lst File to C program in GCC for RISC-V

Tags: assembly, gcc, disassembly, riscv

I am new to the C programming language and gcc.

I am  using below command to compile my C program . But sometimes i see the generated riscv assembly code does not seem to exactly match   the functionality of C program.

Is there any tool or option in gcc or any technique to write c program  which will help me to map the Riscv Assembly code to my C program code. I.e I want a section of C code maps or refer to which line of LST program.

riscv64-unknown-elf-gcc -O3 -mabi=lp64d -flto -mstrict-align -march=rv64ima -mcmodel=medany -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -D TARGET -D FIXED -I/riscv/env/   -c -o sanity.o sanity.c

riscv64-unknown-elf-gcc crt.S -static  -nostartfiles -lm -lgcc -Xlinker -Tlinker_script.ld -O3 -mabi=lp64d -flto -mstrict-align -march=rv64ima -mcmodel=medany -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -D TARGET -D FIXED  common.o sanity.o -Wl,-Map=riscv.elf.map -o riscv.elf

riscv64-unknown-elf-objdump -d riscv.elf > riscv.lst

Thank you for your help.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/ is good for that; it uses debug info to correlate asm instructions with source line numbers.  See also [How to remove "noise" from GCC/clang assembly output?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38552116).  Also [View Both Assembly and C code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21334308) for `objdump -S`

Comment: (add `-g` to your GCC options for `objdump -S` to work)

Comment: Can it be done to Elf file or it would need .o file. I have many .o files getting generated. Thanks.

Comment: `objdump  -drwC -S` works on `.o` ELF object files, as well as on linked ELF *executables* is the word you're looking for. As long as your linking step didn't strip debug info when linking.

Comment: Thanks Peter, now its working for a small code. hope it works for large code .